# Translating Excel VBA script to Python

Tags: python, vb.net, vba, excel

I have the following VBA script:

```
Sub excelgraphme()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\DRIVE D\graphme\result.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .TextFilePlatform = 866
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with translating with pywin32? And first of all, what should I do with vb statement: WITH END WITH? How i can translate it?

Comment: Moved this from answer to comment per @staticx feedback. There are a number of sites out there that offer conversion help (through tutorials) or as apps to do this. Here is one. You may want to try a google search before posting here as this site is geared toward solving problems with code rather than helping write new code.

Comment: It is not correct. And didn't work. Like another online converters.

Comment: The main problem is     Set qtNew = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\DRIVE D\graphme\result.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1")). I have no idea hot convert it to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library for Python. I rewrote the code, but not sure about the value of `TextFileTextQualifier`. You can see its value (and other variables) by running your VB script.

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

ws = excel.Workbooks.Add().Worksheets(1)
qtNew = ws.QueryTables.Add( "TEXT;C:\\DRIVE D\\graphme\\result.txt", ws.Range("A1"))

qtNew.TextFilePlatform = 866
qtNew.TextFileStartRow = 1
qtNew.TextFileParseType = 1
qtNew.TextFileTextQualifier = 1
qtNew.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
qtNew.TextFileTabDelimiter = True
qtNew.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
qtNew.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
qtNew.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
qtNew.TextFileColumnDataTypes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
qtNew.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
qtNew.Refresh()
```

Comment: Great job! I made some mistakes, but wrote something like that. Thank you. Can you help me with this section:     Range("B3:Q18").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=$C$1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Comment: @xijhoy Unfortunately, I do not have enough time now to do so. This link may be useful: http://pythonexcels.com/mapping-excel-vb-macros-to-python/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is easier to see if I rewrite without the With And End With statements.  With is there so that VBA doesn't have to check that the object (whose method is being called) is Nothing.

```
Sub excelgraphme()
    Dim qtNew As QueryTable
    Set qtNew = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\DRIVE D\graphme\result.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    '* is equivalent but slightly slower because With statement means VBA won't check each line for qtNew=Nothing
    qtNew.TextFilePlatform = 866
    qtNew.TextFileStartRow = 1
    qtNew.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    qtNew.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    qtNew.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    qtNew.TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    qtNew.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    qtNew.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    qtNew.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    qtNew.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    qtNew.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    qtNew.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell me which Excel VBA to Python converters didn't work?  I am pondering writing my own.

Comment: http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/ https://www.varycode.com/